# Could not create tunnel device. Fatal. when running icmptx

Tags: networking, proxy, interface, ifconfig, tunnel

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-wi-fi-evading-authentication-proxy-using-icmptx-0150347/#) on using ICMP protocol to access the internet to bypass a public WiFi's authentication page.

Why do I get `Could not create tunnel device. Fatal.` when I run `icmptx -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`?

Could it be because I don't have a tun0 interface on my Ubuntu laptop? I've tried to set it up with `tunctl` by typing `sudo tunctl -u root -t tun0`, after which running `ifconfig tun0` does return an interface, but I'm still getting the original error... Please help me out, someone!

Comment: Where and when do you get this error?

Comment: Did you check the connectivity with ping ( to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx that i assumed to be the remote side vpn servers ip ) before you connect to the vpn server?

Comment: Yes I did, although I tried connecting straight to Google. Maybe that is where I'm going wrong? Will this only work with VPN?

Comment: @StancuMihai I get the error when I run `icmptx -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` in the terminal.....

Comment: Did u tried with sudo? 'sudo icmptx -s xxx.xxx.xxx.zzz' ?

Comment: @StancuMihai hmmm.. didn't think of that... Will try later thanks